# How to view UTF-8 Characters in Vim or gVim

Tags: vim

I work on webpages involving non-English scripts from time to time, most of them are encoded using UTF-8.

Vim and gVim do not display those UTF-8 characters correctly.

I'm using Vim 7.3.46 on Windows 7, 64-bit, with `set guifont=Monaco:h10` in _vimrc.

Is there a way to fix this?

Update: I've googled around and found `set guifontwide` acts as second fallback for regional languages.

I added the following lines to _vimrc and most of my problems got solved.

```
set enc=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf8,prc
set guifont=Monaco:h11
set guifontwide=NSimsun:h12
```

The above NSimsun font works for Chinese, The problem is, I don't know how they got the font name to work with Vim, `Courier New` is mentioned as `Courier_New` also `NSimsun` is nowhere in the font directory. The font I want to use is `Latha` But, I don't know how to use it in the _vimrc file. `set guifontwide=latha:h12` or `set guifontwide=Latha:h12` doesn't work.

If I successfully set the `guifontwide` to `latha`, then my problem will be solved. How to do it?

Comment: what is the value of `'guifont'` and the value of `'guifontwide'`? Also, what OS are you using and what version of vim?

Comment: Sathish, were you able to find any solution for this? I'm trying to type in gVim with eKalappai software but vim is only showing me ?? characters (apparently saving them the same way).

Comment: @sundar No. I gave up :|

Comment: My problem was that inconsolata-g does not support the utf-8 characters in my document.

Comment: Using `set guifontwide=NSimsun:h12` fails for me, says "Invalid wide font" probably the same non-monospace issue?

Answer (score 73):

Did you try

```
:set encoding=utf-8
:set fileencoding=utf-8
```

?

Comment: I've tried with both these settings, and still I cant see utf-8 characters.

Comment: -1. Actually this cannot work. Neither of these options will reload the file. The first one will modify how vim stores buffers (and other things) internally, the second one will specify that you wish to change the encoding of a file that is already loaded in a buffer, which will apply when saving it.

Comment: `:set encoding=utf8` *WILL* refresh the buffer and if the problem was in incorrect encoding, it will fix it. I added `set fileencoding=utf8` option so you won't run into the most confusing "Can't convert some character" error when saving.

Comment: set encoding worked. I added set encoding=utf8 to .vimrc file and now everything is ok with utf8.

Comment: On OSX, I've added these two lines (without the colons) to my `~/.vimrc` and it worked fine

Comment: Thanks! That did it for me.

Comment: This did work for me for cyrillic after following this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/317661/strange-vim-behaviour) and installing iconv library libiconv on Windows 10. Still no luck with Japanese.

Answer (score 72):

Try to reload the document using:

```
:e! ++enc=utf8
```

If that works you should maybe change the  `fileencodings` settings in your .vimrc.

Comment: Doesn't change anything for me

Comment: **DO NOT** run this before saving your work as it will wipe the changes you have made. `:u` will save you though.

Comment: Also this sets the file to readonly when you do this, so you also need to then run `:set noro`

Comment: Thanks for this. Vim was not rendering utf-8 in my case because I had a block of binary data (multipart/form-data attachment part). When I did `:e! ++enc=utf8`, it did render the utf-8, but complained `[ILLEGAL BYTE in line 286]` (the first binary part line) inside the file. I'm guessing the default behavior is to fall back silently to some other encoding when this happens on Vim opening. For some reason, though, `echo &enc` still reports utf-8 in that case.

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky, `&enc` is the encoding vim uses internally to store buffer contents. The setting that contains the encoding for the current file is `&fenc`

Comment: This worked for me when other things didn't, thanks @Benoit

Answer (score 13):

If Japanese people come here, please add the following lines to your `~/.vimrc`

```
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencodings=iso-2022-jp,euc-jp,sjis,utf-8
set fileformats=unix,dos,mac
```

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840843/how-to-display-utf-8-characters-in-vim-correctly) regarding Japanese characters.

Answer (score 6):

On Microsoft Windows, gvim wouldn't allow you to select non-monospaced fonts. Unfortunately Latha is a non-monospaced font.

There is a hack way to make it happen: Using [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) (you can download Windows binary from http://www.geocities.jp/meir000/fontforge/) to edit the Latha.ttf and mark it as a monospaced font. Doing like this:

1. Load fontforge, select latha.ttf.
2. Menu: Element -> Font Info
3. Select "OS/2" from left-hand list on Font Info dialog
4. Select "Panose" tab
5. Set Proportion = Monospaced
6. Save new TTF version of this font, try it out!

Good luck!

Comment: I could not change latha font to monospace. I followed your steps exactly but the saved file still doesn't work as monospaced font :(

Comment: @Sathish Manohar 1) overwrite the existed TTF file, restart your Windows, and try it. or 2) you can save the TTF to a new file and modify the font name. Install the new TTF file. This new font should be available in your list.

Comment: After all those years (7 years) later, there are several free fonts available for VIM. Google Noto fonts https://www.google.com/get/noto; and Iosveka https://github.com/be5invis/Iosevka/releases are very good alternatives to evaluate.

Answer (score 6):

In Linux, Open the VIM configuration file

```
$ sudo -H gedit /etc/vim/vimrc
```

Added following lines:

```
set fileencodings=utf-8,ucs-bom,gb18030,gbk,gb2312,cp936
set termencoding=utf-8
set encoding=utf-8
```

Save and exit, and terminal command:

```
$ source /etc/vim/vimrc
```

At this time VIM will correctly display Chinese.

Answer (score 6):

this work for me and do not need change any config file

`vim --cmd "set encoding=utf8" --cmd "set fileencoding=utf8" fileToOpen`

Answer (score 2):

Is this problem solved meanwhile?

I had the problem that gvim didn't display *all* unicode characters (but only a subset, including the umlauts and accented characters), while `:set guifont?` was empty; see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22063583/1051649).  After reading here, setting the `guifont` to a sensible value fixed it for me.  However, I don't need characters beyond 2 bytes.

Comment: What is a sensible value for guifont? What did you put in?

Comment: I listed the values which worked for me in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22669647).

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get any other fonts I installed to show up in my Windows GVim editor, so I just switched to `Lucida Console` which has at least somewhat better UTF-8 support.  Add this to the end of your `_vimrc`:

```
" For making everything utf-8
set enc=utf-8
set guifont=Lucida_Console:h9:cANSI
set guifontwide=Lucida_Console:h12
```

Now I see at least some UTF-8 characters.

Comment: in my case cANSI had to be changed to cGREEK (Edit -> Select Font... in GVim), with Consolas font, in order to display a UTF-8 encoded text file with greek characters correctly

Answer (score 1):

On Windows gvim just select "Lucida Console" font.