# VIM - no UTF-8 in menu

Tags: vim, utf-8

I added `set encoding=utf-8` to my _vimrc file. Text in my files is ok but in menu there is no UTF-8 letters. Where is a problem here? Without `set encoding=utf-8`there is no UTF-8 in my files but menu is ok. Problem exists only in gui menu (as on the pictrure). File encodings is ok.

[image: VIM-utf-8 problem]

Comment: What menu do you mean?

Comment: I have added a picture with my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to view UTF-8 Characters in VIM or Gvim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166652/how-to-view-utf-8-characters-in-vim-or-gvim)

Comment: I can't find solution in that topic. Nothing works...

Answer (score 2):

I solved it. I added those lines to my config file:

```
set langmenu=pl_PL   
let $LANG = 'pl_PL'
source $VIMRUNTIME/delmenu.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim
```