# Vi: Upper case umlauts not displayed correctly

Tags: shell, unix, vim, editor

if i cat the file input.csv, umlaut are displayed correctly

Output

```
XXXX
os|Äng
XXX
```

however with `vi` or `vim`, following characters are displayed ▒~D

Output

```
XXXX
Ebénist
Moos|▒~Dnge
XXXX
```

All lowercase umlaut work file , its the uppercase that are not displayed correctly

file encoding is:

```
#file -i input.csv 
input.csv: text/plain; charset=utf-8

LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

rest all `locale value="C"`,
also tried with `LANG=de_DE.UTF-8`.

Any pointers will be helpful?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166652/how-to-view-utf-8-characters-in-vim-or-gvim ? What is your vim configuration?

Comment: My .vimrc is empty, when i add set encoding=utf-8 to the file , it displays correctly